# c# Передача в GridLayoutManager ViewModel

Tags: c#, view, viewmodel

Всем привет. У меня есть некоторая логика, которая создаёт элементы столбиками:

```
var gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Context, ViewModel.ColumnsCount);
```

Во ViewModel у меня есть свойство ColumnsCount, которое отвечает за количество колонок, в зависимости от количества элементов.

Из-за того, что сначала происходит отрисовка View, а потом свойств ViewModel, у меня выдаёт Exception, связанный с тем, что ColumnsCount = 0

Решение проблемы простое (если оно вообще сработает...) - передавать в качестве параметра сразу ViewModel, а в дальнейшем его разворачивать внутри, но как это сделать - не известно. Либо, может как-нибудь дожидаться, пока изменится это свойство и только потом создавать переменную gridLayoutManager. Может подскажите решение?

Проблема:
Нужно передать в GridLayoutManager правильное количество колонок, которое уже просчиталось в свойстве ColumnsCount

```
    public int ColumnsCount (MvxNotifyPropertyChanged подключена здесь для SetProperty)
    {
        get => _columnsCount;
        set => SetProperty(ref _columnsCount, value);
    }
```

P.S. в layout элементы вставляются MvxRecyclerView app:MvxTemplateSelector="@string/Products"

Comment: Решение простое: 0 - допустимое значение логикой View, плюс поддержка INPC во View..

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/FH14G - Получаю Exception здесь, если ставлю 0 (Span count should be at least 1. Provided 0)

Comment: `get => _columnsCount < 1 ? 1 : _columnsCount` так работает?

Comment: ColumnsCount = ProductsCount % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 3;

Comment: Это а конструкторе вьюмодели код?

Comment: Там есть свойство ProductsCollection, которое изменяется, когда получает из БД значения. В set вставлена данная логика (это всё во ViewModel)

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что это происходит не моментально, а через какое-то время, когда сервер даст ответ. Из-за этого LayoutManager берёт старое значение ColumnsCount, которое чуть позже изменяется

Comment: Зачем вы обсуждаете то, что на момент запроса геттера свойства еще не выполнилось? Я вам геттер показываю, а вы как бы не замечаете.

Comment: У свойства get => _columnsCount

Comment: `get => _columnsCount < 1 ? 1 : _columnsCount;` так работает?

Comment: Нет. Если передавать в var gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Context, ViewModel.ColumnsCount);, то тут по BreakPoint устанавливает 1, а потом, когда свойство изменяется, выдаётся Exception, т.к. ColumnsCount уже значение 3

Comment: У меня не хвтает воображения чтобы вообразить ваш код полностью.

Comment: Нашел решение: отрисовывать View, после того, как отработает метод ViewModelPropertyChanged. Он, вроде, как отвечает за изменение свойств, поэтому идеально подходит. Логику просто переместил туда

Comment: Отлично, `поддержка INPC во View` - именно это я и имел в виду.

Comment: Единственное, нужно ли отписываться от данного события, после его работы или оставлять как есть?

Comment: Подписываться нужно при создании View, отписываться при уничножении. Все контролы - IDisposable. Кстати, рассмотрите схему DependencyProperty+Binding, тогда вручную не придется подписываться и отписываться.